# Git: When working off a fork, do you rebase off of your origin or the upstream?

Tags: git, github

I work for a company who's github doesn't allow direct pushes so I have a fork of the repo as `origin` and the corp. repo as `upstream`

```
origin git@github.com:Me/company-repo.git (fetch)  # my fork
origin git@github.com:Me/company-repo.git (push)   # my fork
upstream git@github.com:company-repo.git (fetch)
upstream git@github.com:company-repo.git (push)
```

So I have my feature branch `feature/newFeature` that I worked on for a few weeks and it's behind master.  I want to rebase it against master and force push it to my feature branch so that I am up to date with master.
What is the proper way to do that ...rebase against `origin` or `upstream` master?

Comment: Ah, so you just want to update the branch of your forked copy. That's not necessary really as a PR will handle that unless there are features in `master` that is required in your branch.

Comment: @astrochun there are a few potential conflicts so that why I was trying to rebase and take care of them rather than waiting to merge the PR in

Comment: I would recommend just creating the PR as WIP and you can see the conflicts there.

Answer (score 1):

You'd usually want to rebase against the target branch. The target branch in that case is in the upstream repository (that's where your code eventually ends up).

In fact, you are always rebasing against commits contained in a branch. You want to make sure that after your rebase operation all required commits are parent commits of your feature branch.

Your fork's master/main branch will usually be behind the upstream master/main, unless you actively sync it. This can be done from GitHub UI (I think), or manually on the command line:

```
git fetch upstream
git push . upstream/master:master
git push origin master:master
```